# Replacing static text content inside ngrepeat with ngclick directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've tried so many different things here with no luck. Basically i have an array of strings (just sentences). I need to ngRepeat over those and output them. No problem. But I need to be able to do a find and replace for a particular word combination ("social security" in this case), wrap it inside a link and add an ngClick directive to that link.

I'm pretty certain that i need to use a directive and this has something to do with compiling and linking. But Thats about as far as i can get with this. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/Z9CHL/2/
I'm not sure it's the best implementation, but at least it works

The HTML code is quite simple, I send the custom directive one parameter, the full sentence

```
    <ul ng-repeat='sentence in list'>
        <li><span the-dir txt="sentence"></span></li>
    </ul>
```

On the javascript side, it's quite easy but longer :

```
.directive('theDir', function($compile){
var r=/(social security)/ig;
return { 
    scope:{txt:'='},
    link:function(scope,element,attributes){
        scope.aFunction=function(){
         console.log('In the directive, you clicked on social security');   
        }
        if(r.test(scope.txt)) {
            splitted=scope.txt.split(r);
            console.log(splitted)
            var newSpan=new angular.element('<span>');
            for(var i=0;i<splitted.length;i++)
            {
                if(r.test(splitted[i])){
                    var newLink=new angular.element('<a>');
                    newLink.attr('ng-click','aFunction()');
                    newLink.addClass('social-security');
                    newLink.html(splitted[i]);
                    newSpan.append(newLink);
                }
                 else
                     newSpan.append(splitted[i]);
            }
            element.append(newSpan);
            $compile(newSpan)(scope);
        }
        else
        {
         element.html(scope.txt);   
        }

    }

}
});
```

I use a Regular Expression to find all occurrences of your sentence 'social security', split the full sentence on these occurences, then replace each time the words by a new angular.element (an HTML link in this case, with a ng-click attribute). I append all the regular words and the links to the original element, and then $compile the newly created span with the working links in order to have a working ng-click.
And it seems to work
I let you dig in the code, and I hope it helps you

Have fun